# Does c# compiler turns it into c or intel assembly code?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, compilation

After compiling c# what is happening to the code? Computer can't read c# so it should become assembly, moreover, machinde codes.

Comment: Neither.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language

Comment: C# code is compiled into IL code. When you run .Net application JIT compiler compiles IL code into machine instructions

Comment: The [Common Intermediate Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) runs on the [Common Language Runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime).

Comment: Not really clear why this was closed when the moderator closing it provided the answer to the question.

Comment: @Eric Because "what is happening to the code" really isn't a specific enough question. The compilation and assembly process for bytecode VMs is an entire few college courses, and the OP's question wasn't about anything particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C# compiler compiles to IL, Intermediate Language. This is a machine code for a virtual machine. When the code is executed on a real machine it is further compiled by the just-in-time compiler (JIT) which emits true machine code. It's the latter code, that emitted by the JIT compiler, that is actually executed.

Comment: So c# is also kind of like Java. It uses .NET Framework like Java Virtual Machine?